# A system of ODE with algebraic multiplicity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$y'=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &2\\
> -2&-3 \\
> \end{pmatrix}y$$

I have found the eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$ (algebraic multiplicity of 2) and the eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ how should I approach the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $y'=Ay$ is given by
$$y(x)=e^{Ax}y(0)$$
where $e^{Ax}$ is a square matrix that is usually calculated from extracting Jordan form, i.e.
$$A=PJP^{-1}\implies e^{Ax}=P\,e^{Jx}P^{-1}$$
and $P$ can be obtained from [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector), one of which you have already calculated:
$$P=\pmatrix{v_1&v_2}=\pmatrix{-1&-1/2\\1&0}$$
Therefore:
$$J=\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1}\implies e^{Jx}=\pmatrix{1&x\\0&1}e^{-x}$$